# How can i pull dynamic data using v-model and moment js

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, vuejs3, v-model

I can already pull the data from api with v-model, but this is how i see the date `2022-04-23T13:39:00+03:00` but I want it to come this way `2022-04-23 13:39`

Here is my html code

```html
<Field
  class="form-control"
  type="text"
  v-model="date"
  name="date"
  :placeholder="$t('form.label.date')"
/>
```

Here is my ts code

```js
  data() {
    date:"",
  }
  setup() {
    const dateFormat = (date) => {
      return moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    };
  }
```

Comment: I would recommend not using moment js https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: So what do you recommend ? @tauzN

Comment: I use [Day.js](https://day.js.org/)

Comment: We might need more information about what your goal is. Are you just trying to display the date? is the user editing it in a formatted way and then it is stored in a specific format? Is it mutable through `v-model` only?

Comment: @Daniel my goal is to properly display complex data from api like "2022-04-23 13:39" i'm not sure if v-model is used, if you have other alternative ways I'd be happy to hear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only rendering the value and don't need to setup two-way binding  or reactivity, you can just resolve the formatting before passing the formatted value to the template.

You can also pass a formatter function to the template that will render the formatting to you liking.

While there are several options for formatting dates. To avoid adding additional dependencies, I'm using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` in the example. It's a little hacky, since the format is not in any international standard (or it is, and just don't know which one). I've also used [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) with success, but as mentioned in the comments, you should not be using moment. Moment is built in a way that doesn't allow tree-shaking unused parts during packaging, so leads to bloat.

```js
const formatter = (dateStr) => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr)
  if (isNaN(date)) return "-- invalid date --";

  // fr-CA for YYYY-MM-DD + en-GB for 24hour hh:mm:ss
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-CA', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    timeZone: 'UTC'
  }).format(date) + " " + new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric',
    timeZone: 'UTC'
  }).format(date)
}

Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const date = Vue.ref("2022-04-23T13:39:00+03:00");

    // using ref
    const dateFormatted = formatter(date.value);

    return {
      date, // date string ref, to allow reactivity
      dateFormatted, // pass non-reactive value to display
      formatter // pass formatter function if reactive changes are needed
    }
  }
}).mount("#app");
```

```css
input {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.31/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>Date (v-model)<br/><input v-model="date" /></p>
  <p>Formatted with Intl (read-only)<br/> <input :value="dateFormatted" disabled/></p>
  <p>Reactive formatted with Intl (read-only)<br/> <input :value="formatter(date)" disabled /></p>
</div>
```